# working with twitter API and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, twitter

i am currently working on a project where i have to collect and analyze public tweets. For the collection of tweets i prefer to store them in mongodb and also, after research, i came to know that i have to build a twitter application inorder to get OAuth tokens ( http://www.sitepoint.com/twitter-1-1-oauth-php/). My question is, what does a twitter application mean here? Does it mean that only through that application i can store tweets in my mongodb??  Or does it mean that once i get these authentication tokens i can use any program(preferably ruby) to extract tweets??

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Login to https://dev.twitter.com/, create an app. In the dialog that appears, Just add an URL to any of your github repositories.

To my understanding, to use the Twitter API at all, you needed (at least in 2011) to register an app with a valid URL, however trivial the app might be. Don't know if the app itself was really validated by a Twitter employee/bot at app-registration-time, or if you just needed to provide an URL to a github repository. I don't know which other types of repository are possible.

I think, the explicit oauth mechanism requires all this. ([Explation for stackexchange](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication))

In order to present an authentication "conversation", twitter has to show your apps (that consume twitter services) an url to another app (to be found on the internet) which is linked in some way to your twitter account. So twitter can start counting the free API requests made, number of calls per hour remaining, etc.